# PHP + Mssql Not Displaying Results

Tags: php, angularjs, sql-server, json

Connect to MSSQL

```
session_start();

// CONEXION

$link = mssql_connect('xxx.xxx.xx.xx', 'xxx', 'xxx');
mssql_select_db("xxx",$link);

if (!$link || !mssql_select_db('BDFlexline', $link)) {
    die('No se puede conectar o seleccionar una base de datos!');
}
// FIN CONEXION

if( isset( $_GET["dcto"] ) ){
    $dcto = $_GET["dcto"];
    $empresa = $_GET['empresa'];
}
```

query here

```
$conn ="SELECT 
D.TIPODOCTO, d.CORRELATIVO, d.CLIENTE,coalesce(c.razonsocial,'') RAZONSOCIAL, 
v.DESCRIPCION as VENDEDOR , D.NUMERO, D.FECHA, D.TOTAL, d.Local as CLUB 
from documento D 
left join Vendedor v on d.Empresa = v.EMPRESA and d.Vendedor = v.CODIGO
left join ctacte c on c.empresa=d.empresa and c.tipoctacte=d.tipoctacte and c.ctacte =d.idctacte 
where  d.total >= 0 
and d.aprobacion not in ('S','N') 
and d.tipodocto='".$dcto."' 
and d.empresa='".$empresa."'  
and d.vigencia not in ('N','A') 
and d.Fecha between CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), DATEADD(mm, -1, DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GETDATE())-1),GETDATE())),105) 
and CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,GETDATE()))),DATEADD(mm,1,GETDATE())),105)
order by d.numero";
```

The query is ok, work as intended from within the SQL management console, but php ...

```
    $result= mssql_query($conn, $link);

############# PRUEBA 1 #################
    $json = array();     

do {  
    while ($row = mssql_fetch_object($result)){  
        $json[] = $row;     
    }  
}while ( mssql_next_result($result) ); 
echo json_encode($json);
mssql_close($link);
```

The result is [] but must be:

```
[{"TIPODOCTO":"COTIZACION","CORRELATIVO":"3059","CLIENTE":"20548547-2","RAZONSOCIAL":"SERVICIOS AIR LMTD","VENDEDOR":"Diana","NUMERO":"0000003079","FECHA":{"date":"2017-07-03 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Berlin"},"TOTAL":"3111964.00000000","CLUB":"ADM"},
{"TIPODOCTO":"COTIZACION","CORRELATIVO":"3062","CLIENTE":"71540800-7","RAZONSOCIAL":"UNIVERSIDAD SAC","VENDEDOR":"Ernesto","NUMERO":"0000003482","FECHA":{"date":"2017-07-05 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Berlin"},"TOTAL":"16670624.00000000","CLUB":"ADM"}] .... and more
```

I need the result in json format beacause im using angularJS. 
Thanks for any idea

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the values of $dcto or $empressa are wrong causing a blank result set.  For a test do

```
echo "conn=$conn<br/>";
```

and see what shows on the screen.  Then run that query in the console and make sure it gives you the results you want.

Comment: thanks Thread7,  

EDITED:

conn= select D.TIPODOCTO, d.CORRELATIVO, d.CLIENTE,coalesce(c.razonsocial,'') RAZONSOCIAL, v.DESCRIPCION as VENDEDOR , D.NUMERO, D.FECHA, D.TOTAL, d.Local as CLUB from documento D left join Vendedor v on d.Empresa = v.EMPRESA and d.Vendedor = v.CODIGO left join ctacte c on c.empresa=d.empresa and c.tipoctacte=d.tipoctacte and c.ctacte =d.idctacte where d.total >= 0 and d.aprobacion not in ('S','N') and d.tipodocto='COTIZACION' and d.empresa='E01' ...

the query look good, the problem maybe is in mssql_fetch_object

Comment: Is it actually going into the while loop?  Put an echo "Inside While Loop"; and see.  If not, then maybe something wrong with your $link or mssql_select_db statement.  Another thing to try is a very simple query. Like $conn ="SELECT * from documento";  If that produces no results then obviously nothing to do with the query.  Finally, what version of PHP?  mssql_fetch_object was deprecated and removed from PHP 7.